# Python functions and strings

Tags: python

How would i use a function to grab specific parts of a string?
Say for instance my string consisted of data such as the following:
'12345678 123456.78 Doe, John D.'  # Data that could be representative of bank software#
How do i tell python to make the first chars of the string an int, the second part of the string to be a float and the last part should automatically remain a string right?

```
for line in file_obj:
    print(line) #would yield something like this '12345678 123456.78 Doe, John D.'
```

If i had functions like:

```
def find_balance():
    return float  

def find_acc_num():
    return int
def find_name():
    return str
```

What would my parameters be?  Would for iteration be the best way to solve the problem?  I want to be able to change account information (balances and names) as long as the user can supply the correct account number.  I am new to using functions and am a bit unsure how to go about doing this...

Thanks in advance for any help i really appreciate it. =D

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with a `maxsplit` of 2:

```
>>> s = '12345678 123456.78 Doe, John D.'
>>> 
>>> v = s.split(None, 2)
>>> int(v[0]), float(v[1]), v[2]
(12345678, 123456.78, 'Doe, John D.')
```

Comment: Nice, I had no idea there was a maxsplit argument. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Probably homework but I am bored

```
for line in file_obj:
    #Make a list of parts separated by spaces and new lines
    #The second argument says to only split up the first two things
    parts = line.split(None, 2)
    #Assign each value
    theint = int(parts[0])
    thefloat = float(parts[1])
    thestring = parts[3].strip()
```

You could do this in multiple functions by passing each function the parts if you wanted.

Edit: Changed code to use max length at suggestion of @arshajii . Also stripped the newline at the end of thestring.

Comment: You don't need to do the wasteful rejoining at the end, you just need two splits.

Comment: Thank you!  Very helpful.  Quick question--does .split() make a list automatically?  Or is that just pythons way to represent items separated from a string?

Comment: @RobertSchneeberger it makes a list automatically. In that code ```line``` is a string, and its method ```split``` returns a list that is then stored into ```parts```.

Comment: This code gives me error could not convert string to float at thefloat = float(parts[1])

Comment: @RobertSchneeberger That error happens if the string is incorrectly formatted. There has to be a number there. The error will be something like
```ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'something'```

Does the string make sense? Is your file correct?

Comment: do i have to use .strip() on thefloat = float(parts[1]) to get it formatted correctly to convert it to a float?

Comment: I cannot use list dictionary or map on this anyways lol thanks though gonna have to find a dif way to do it besides split

Comment: Hahah. Oh boy have fun with that. And you wouldn't have had to use strip on the float. You do have to strip the end of the line (which I updated in my answer) but the float is in the middle and shouldn't be a problem.